# Highlighting Date in Vim

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I have a file that has dates in this format: `Fri Jun 05, 2015`.  It's essentially a diary.

I have created the syntax keywords `Day`, `Month`, `dateNum`, and `Year` for the various components of the date but I want to highlight the date as a single entity.  Is it possible to create a syntax rule that is a sequence of keywords?

Here's the contents of my syntax file so far.

```
syn match Code '`.*`'
syn match Time '[01][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\(:[0-5][0-9]\)\?'

syn keyword Day Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun, nextgroup=Month
syn keyword Month Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec nextgroup=dateNum

syn match dateNum '[0-3][0-9],'  nextgroup=Year
syn match Year '\d\{4}'

syn region Code start="`" end="`"
```

I am manually setting the highlighting for these groups for the time being (e.g. `hi Time gui=bold`).

Here's a sample diary file.  Note that the highlighting for `Time` and `Code` already work.

```
Sun Jun 07, 2015

23:48 Checked out `bleeding-edge` branch.

Mon Jun 08, 2015

09:17 Woke up

09:18 Hit snooze.
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes; you can just combine the keywords in a long `:syntax match` sequence. For example:

```
augroup diary
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme,BufRead,BufNewFile *
        \  syntax match DiaryDate "\v(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d\d, \d\d\d\d"
        \| highlight DiaryDate ctermbg=green guibg=green
augroup END
```

[image]

Comment: I was hoping that I could use the keywords I already generated.  Is that possible?

I also don't understand some of the syntax.  What is the `\v` at the start of the match string?  And, what does the escaped-pipe, `\|` mean?

Comment: @Stephen the `\v` is the [very magic]( http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Simplifying_regular_expressions_using_magic_and_no-magic) regex switch it makes all characters having a special meaning excepted `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and `_`